# Bottom action bar on android froyo (api 8)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-2.2-froyo

Has anyone found a way to get a bottom action bar on android versions older than 4 (api 14)? I am reading [the tutorial and it says](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar) I need api 14. But I know folks have often found ways around similar boundaries. I appreciate any leads.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in < 14 API useing **[actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)** just add that library in your Project.

see here i have code like

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add("Save").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        menu.add("Search").setShowAsAction(
                MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                        | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
        SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu("Options");
        sub.add(0, SubMenu.NONE, 0, "First");
        sub.add(0, SubMenu.NONE, 1, "Second");
        sub.add(0, SubMenu.NONE, 2, "Three");
        sub.getItem().setShowAsAction(
                MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                        | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
        // HERE IS WHere I AM FACING PROBLEM IN
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        MenuItem actionItem = menu
                .findItem(R.id.menu_item_share_action_provider_action_bar);
        ShareActionProvider actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem
                .getActionProvider();
        actionProvider
                .setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME); // this
                                                                                                // is
                                                                                                // BRILLIANT
                                                                                                // WAY
                                                                                                // TO
                                                                                                // AVOID
                                                                                                // REPEATation
        actionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private Intent createShareIntent() {

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hi hello");

        return sharingIntent;
    }
}
```

an in android manifest i have add `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

---

### so o/p is in (Galaxy Tab Android 2.3.3)

[image]

---

[image]

---

### Galaxy POP (Android 2.1)

[image]

[image]

### this is just sample for your understanding. use less option then its fullfeel your requirment.

Comment: What if you put the device in `landscape` mode?

Comment: My point was that the split won't work when in `landscape` mode ;-)

Comment: I think the problem with splitting the actions between the top and bottom is that it would make it more difficult to perform actions. Actions should be the most important things to do on an Activity -- splitting them between the top and bottom of the screen means users need to look in two places rather than one. --> by **RetoMeier** : https://plus.google.com/+RetoMeier/posts/Z3unhccSDvy